# how to access last index of array from split function inside awk?

Tags: arrays, shell, indexing, awk, split

How can i do this using awk?

Example -

```
awk '{split($1,A,"."); print A[-1], $1, $2, $3, $4}'
```

Sample input and output.

Input

```
123 456 abc.def.ghi 789 
321 654 qaz.wsx.edc.rfv 987
```

Output

```
ghi 123 456 abc.def.ghi 789  
rfv 321 654 qaz.wsx.edc.rfv 987
```

Comment: can you clarify if you want to split first field or the third field?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If your problem is exactly as the example in your question, take the answer from @muzido, `$NF` will give you the last field.

If you just want to know the last element of an array by `split()`:

`split()` function will return you how many elements it has just "splitted",  test with your code: `awk '{print split($1,A,".")}' file` you will see the number. Then you can just use it by:

```
awk '{n=split($1,A,"."); print A[n]}' file 
# n is the length of array A
```

Comment: @anshulgupta you can even: `print A[split($1,A,".")]` ;-)

Comment: Let me know if you can optimize it further before i finalize my code ;)

Comment: @anshulgupta it is not a kind of "optimization", I think the line in my answer (with `n` variable), is more readable.

Answer (score 11):

If you have GNU `awk`, you can try the function `length` on a array:

```
awk '{split($1,A,"."); print A[length(A)]}'
```

Comment: `length()` function here is redundant

Comment: @Kent I agree that `split()` and `length()` are kind of redundant together. However I find nice to have `length()`  working with an array.

Comment: @Oliv, it's sad that i can only mark one as correct answer!

Comment: Why would you run length() on an array when split() just returned the length of the array?

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
$ awk '{print A[split($3,A,".")],$0}' input.txt
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Kent already gave you the split() answer but you don't need split creating/using an array for this, e.g. with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/.*\./,"",1,$3), $0}' file
ghi 123 456 abc.def.ghi 789
rfv 321 654 qaz.wsx.edc.rfv 987
```