# Strip directory from filename in checksum output

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have the output of a checksum used in a unix shell script, and I need only the checksum value and the filename to be displayed.

```
$ Cksum path/path2/f1.txt | awk '{print $1,$2}'
1237668 path/path2/f1.txt
```

However I want the filename without the directory:

```
1237668 f1.txt
```

I have tried sed by which I only get the filename and not the checksum:

```
$ Cksum path/path2/f1.txt | sed 's/.*path2//'
/f1.txt
```

Comment: You need to replace `$2` by `$3`, as `$2` contains the filesize, not the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your filenames don't contain spaces, here are are `sed` and `awk` solution:

A simpler `sed`:

```sh
cksum path/to/f.txt | sed 's/ .*[/ ]/ /'

878395353 f.txt
```

This `sed` starts match from space character and matches until it gets last `/` or space since `.*` is greedy. We just replace this matched text with a single space.

---

Or a simpler `awk` using `/` or space as input field separator:

```sh
cksum path/to/f.txt | awk -F '[ /]' '{print $1, $NF}'

878395353 f.txt
```

Comment: As an aside; with sed and the substitution command, normally the delimiter used is the forward slash `/` but can be changed to another character if it makes the regex/replacement easier (as you have chosen `~`). However, in this case since the `/` is inside the bracket expression, there is no need to change the delimiter, so `sed 's/ .*[/ ]/ /' file` works as well and perhaps is easier on the eye?

Comment: Thank you.  I did use this . Cksum path1/path2/filename.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";} { print $1, $NF} and I get now checksumvalue size filename.txt.  I want to get rid of the size, but unable to.

Comment: I have used cksum path/path2/f1.txt | awk 'BEGIN {print $1,$NF}| awk 'print$1, $3}'    AND get the required output..works

Comment: You don't need to use 2 awk actually. It can be done in a single awk

Answer (score 0):

Based on `man cksum`

> The cksum utility writes to the standard output three whitespace
> separated fields for each input file.  These fields are a checksum
> CRC, the total number of octets in the file and the file name.

Using `sed` you could use 3 capture groups and use group 1 and 3 in the replacement.

```
([^[:space:]]+) [^[:space:]]+ (.*/)?([^[:space:]]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `([^[:space:]]+)` Group 1, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `[^[:space:]]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char between spaces
- `(.*/)?` Optionally match group 2 matching until the last occurrence of `/`
- `([^[:space:]]+)` Group 3, match 1+ non whitespace chars

For example:

```
cksum ./file.txt # --> 3777026118 8 ./file.txt
```

Using `sed`

```
cksum ./file.txt | sed -E 's~([^[:space:]]+) [^[:space:]]+ (.*/)?([^[:space:]]+)~\1 \3~'
```

Output

```
3777026118 file.txt
```

---

Using `awk` printing the first field and the last item from the result of splitting the 3rd field:

```
cksum ./file.txt | awk '
{
  n=split($3,a,"/")
  print $1, a[n]
}'
```

Output

```
3777026118 file.txt
```

Comment: The Perl extension `\S` might not be available in `sed` even with `-E`. Anyway, simply `'s%[^[:space:]]+/%%'` should work portably, assuming you don't have an file names with spaces in them (which this answer already seems to assume).

Comment: @tripleee I see, thanks for pointing that out. I tested this on my Mac and it did not work with the `\S`. Now it does on Ubuntu and Mac using `[^[:space:]]+`

Comment: Still a bit complex for my taste, but thanks for the fix. The `/g` is still superfluous; you don't expect (and could not have) more than one match per line.

Answer (score 0):

Awk can do this. For example:

`awk  '{ printf("%d", $1); n=split($2,a,"/"); print(" ", a[n])}'`

Tested with:

```
echo "1237668 path/path2/f1.txt"  | awk  '{ printf("%d", $1); n=split($2,a,"/"); print(" ", a[n])}'

1237668  f1.txt
```

The first element is just a print with $1 in the printf.
The second is a split on / then print the last element:

[How to split a delimited string into an array in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009664/how-to-split-a-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-awk)

[how to access last index of array from split function inside awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703124/how-to-access-last-index-of-array-from-split-function-inside-awk)

Answer (score 0):

Note: I do not know the `Cksum` command you use. My `cksum` outputs 3 fields: checksum, size and filename. Adapt the indexes in the following if yours behaves differently.

If your shell is `bash`, you could use a `bash` array and `basename`. If you don't have spaces in your filenames:

```
$ a=($(cksum path/path2/f1.txt))
$ printf '%s %s\n' "${a[0]}" "$(basename ${a[2]})"
857691210 f1.txt
```

If you have spaces in your filenames, adapt the `printf` parameters:

```
$ a=($(cksum "path/path2/f 1.txt"))
$ printf '%s %s\n' "${a[0]}" "$(basename "${a[*]:2}")"
857691210 f 1.txt
```

And if you prefer quoting the filename:

```
$ printf '%s "%s"\n' "${a[0]}" "$(basename "${a[*]:2}")"
857691210 "f 1.txt"
```

Comment: I didn't test this, but `a[0]` and `a[2]`, no `a[1]`?

Comment: The OP apparently want only the checksum and the file's basename, not the size.

Comment: Oh, the size, I forgot about that. So you say that the original question should contain `$3` instead of `$2`: `awk '{print $1, $3}'`?

Comment: Yeah, probably. Unless this `Cksum` (uppercase `C`) the OP use is different from my `cksum`...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
cd $(dirname path/path2/f1.txt); cksum $(basename path/path2/f1.txt)
```

or, to keep the current directory the same:

```
a=$(pwd); cd $(dirname path/path2/f1.txt); cksum $(basename path/path2/f1.txt); cd $a
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `/` character only occurs in field #2, delete everything after field #2; then remove the directory name:

```
 Cksum path/path2/f1.txt | 
 sed 's# [^/]*$##;s# .*/# #'
```